# How to construct an exception in Test Class

Tags: unit-test, exception

I want to cover the following lines of code:

```js
@TestVisible
    private void sendEmailToAdminOnFailure(Exception e){
        String body = '';
        body += 'Failure:--------------->'+e.getMessage()+'\n';
        body += 'Stack Trace=============>'+e.getStackTraceString()+'\n';
        //more code here
}
```

My Test code is as follows:

```js
Exception exception1;
classObject.sendEmailToAdminOnFailure(exception1);
```

I am getting the following error:
`FATAL_ERROR System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`

How do I set the `Message` and `StackTraceString` for the exception? I tried `exception1.setMessage('Test message');` but I get `NullPointerException` for the line.

I found the following on [this site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) but I am not able to use it:

[image: exception methods]

I referred [this site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) too but didn't find any solution. Please guide. Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined a variable, but haven't initialized it.

Unitialized variables are always null (until you assign a value or instance of the type).

bad

```java
Exception exception1;
// exception1 hasn't been initialized, so you're trying to call
//   null.setMessage().
// null.<anything> pretty much guarantees a Null Pointer Exception
exception1.setMessage('my message');
```

good

```java
Exception exception1 = new System.MathException();
exception1.setMessage('my message');
```

The general `System.Exception` type can't be constructed, but subclasses of `System.Exception` (like `System.MathException`) can.

Comment: AFAIR there's also a constructor(String) which creates an exception with passed string as message